# For loop function doesn't work within a while loop

Tags: bash, loops

I am looking to repeat the same function for each gene in my genelist. This is what the while loop does. Then it extracts the files from the master document into a new bed file.

The number_of_lines variable is the number of rows in the document. And I want to create a document with the number of row corresponding to number_of_lines

i.e.

number_of_lines=1

output

```
1
```

number_of_lines=5

output

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

my code below

```
while read gene
do
    grep -w $gene $masterfile | awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$4}' > $gene.bed
    number_of_lines=$(grep "^.*$" -c $gene.bed)
    echo $number_of_lines
    cat "" > $gene.1.bed
    for i in 'eval echo {1..$number_of_lines}'
    do
        echo $number_of_lines >> $gene.1.bed
    done
done < $genelist
```

if I do this by itself

```
cat "" > $gene.1.bed
for i in 'eval echo {1..$number_of_lines}'
do
    echo $number_of_lines >> $gene.1.bed
done
```

it works?

Comment: You need to put `eval echo {1..$number_of_lines}` inside `$()` not single quotes.

Comment: You can also write `for ((i=0; i<$number_of_lines; i++))`

Comment: Why are you using `grep` to get the number of lines instead of `wc -l`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to put `eval echo {1..$number_of_lines}` inside `$()` to expand to the output.
2. `cat ""` will get an error, that should be `echo ""`. But simpler is to just put the output redirection around the entire loop instead of after each `echo` statement.

```
while read gene
do
    grep -w "$gene" "$masterfile" | awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$4}' > "$gene.bed"
    number_of_lines=$(grep "^.*$" -c "$gene.bed")
    echo $number_of_lines
    for i in $(eval echo {1..$number_of_lines})
    do
        echo $number_of_lines
    done > "$gene.1.bed"
done < "$genelist"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you see `eval`, you "know" your code is wrong. @Barmar already pointed out the normal construction `for ((i=0; i<$number_of_lines; i++))`, what should be used here. With all lines having the same content, you have another possibility: `yes`. I made some other changes too.

```
while read gene
do
    grep -w "${gene}" "${masterfile}" |
        awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t";} {print $1, $2, $3, $5, $6, $4}' > "${gene}.bed"
    number_of_lines=$(wc -l < "${gene}.bed")
    echo "${number_of_lines}"
    yes "${number_of_lines}" | head -"${number_of_lines}" > "${gene}.1.bed"
done < "${genelist}"
```